# Reauthenticating Firebase users with email and password

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase with an iOS app to authenticate users.

With Google Sign-in, we can use `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()` to automatically authenticate a user when they (re-)start the app.

What is the recommended way to re-authenticate a user with email and password? We don't want to store email and password locally on the client, do we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user first signs into your app, Firebase automatically stores this info in the iOS keychain so they don't have to re-sign up every time they open your app. To check if a user is currently logged in; even after quitting out of your app, you'd do `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser` and check to see if its `nil`. This info is stored until they explicitly log out of your app.